# How to make refresh forcefully neglecting the data cached if any

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching, codeigniter-2

Let me explain the need for this. I have a page where user can upload his profile picture if he needs to change it. On submission of that form i am suppose to show him his profile page.

But the issue is this, Both his old profile image & his new profile image which gets uploaded are stored by same name & same extension(this is required, i cannot change this else i wouldnt have had the problem if i had changed the name of the new image)

So when he is redirected to his profile page, still the old image shows up unless the user hits Ctrl+F5. So is there any way to solve this ?

P.S : I know abt random query string on img src method. But i dont want that since it will always get image from server. I just want the browser not to cache the image only on this particular request(eg setting status header in function which redirects after image upload). I am using Codeigniter, PHP

Answer (score 0):

Try `$this->output->set_header();` for the image.

[From the docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/output.html):

> Permits you to manually set server headers, which the output class will send for you when outputting the final rendered display.

```
$this->output->set_header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', $last_update).' GMT');
$this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
$this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0");
```

Comment: I have already have this code in my constructor

 `$this->set_header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');`
 `$this->set_header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0');`
 `$this->set_header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', FALSE);`
 `$this->set_header('Pragma: no-cache');`

Comment: You need to send these headers for the image, not your page. Images are requested seperatly from the browser and the `cache-control` of the image has nothing to do with the one of the page.

Comment: i havent used $this->output since this code is in my MY_Output Class :)

Comment: If you dont generate your image with PHP you maybe need to edit your server configuration. In apache2 the `000-default` or something like that.

Comment: Can u point me to url where i can read more about this method u said :)

Comment: try [this guide](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-speed-cache-control.html)